# what's wrong with the golang regexp.matchString?

Tags: go

can any one explain why does this match [play](https://play.golang.org/p/NJXD-nKnu7)?

Source:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    match, _ := regexp.MatchString("[a-z]+", "test?")
    fmt.Printf("the result of match: %v", match)
}
```

isn't the golang's `regexp.MatchString` is fully match? I can't understand and I am a newbie for golang

Comment: *isn't the golang's regexp.MatchString is fully match?* No, it's not.

Comment: is there any fully match function?

Comment: Just add anchors to your expression: `^[a-z]+$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression "[a-z]+" will match "test" is the search text "test?".
Similarly, it will match "**testing** testing", "2001 **a** space oddessy", etc.

Go lang's [regexp package](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) matches search text according to the *syntax* and *meaning* of the regular expression. There isn't a method which *itself* tries to match the regular expression with the entire search text, and gives up if it can't, *unless* the regular expression defines that an entire search-text-match is the required behaviour.

The syntax of regular expressions does enable matching the entire search text.

**'^'**, the start-anchor symbol at the start of the regular expression forces the match to include the start of the search text.
**'$'**, the end-anchor symbol at the end of the regular expression forces the match to include the end of the search text.
They have different meaning in other positions within a regular expression.

As @TomCooper commented, use both start and end anchors around the regular expression pattern you are looking for. These anchor the enclosed regular expression to the start and end of the search text to ensure the entire search text matches the regular expression.

Comment: @toolchainX - thank you! Your question seemed reasonable to me, so I don't really understand the down votes without any links to existing answers or the web. Best of luck using Go; IMHO it is a lovely language.